# How to get innertext in an XML

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnode, innertext

I have the following XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Comprobante version="2.2" serie="A" folio="35207" fecha="2013-05-31T11:51:48">
 <Emisor rfc="" nombre="E">
  <DomicilioFiscal calle="" noExterior="" colonia="" />
  <ExpedidoEn calle="" noExterior="" colonia="" />
  <RegimenFiscal Regimen="Regimen" />
 </Emisor>

 <Receptor rfc="" nombre="Z">
  <Domicilio calle="" noExterior="" colonia="" />
 </Receptor>

 <Conceptos cantidad="1.000" unidad="COMISION" descripcion="PENDIENTE" valorUnitario="28.50000" importe="28.50" />

 <Impuestos totalImpuestosTrasladados="3.14">
  <Traslados>
   <Traslado impuesto="IVA" tasa="11.00" importe="3.14" />
  </Traslados>
 </Impuestos>

 <Addenda>
  <ener:EstadoDeCuentaCombustible xmlns:ener="">
   <ener:cadenaOriginal>||2.2|A|35207|2013-05-31T11:51:48|773463|2011|ingreso|Pago en una sola exhibicion|28.50|31.64|Tarjeta|Tijuana,Baja California|3213|ERE|E S.A. de C.V.|Prol|13351|Anexa e|Tijuana|Tijuana|Baja California|Mexico|22100|Prol|13351|Anexa e|Tijuana|Tijuana|Baja California|Mexico|22100|Regimen|XA|Z||||TIJUANA|TIJUANA|BAJA CALIFORNIA|Mexico||1.000|COMISION|PENDIENTE|28.50000|28.50|IVA|11.00|3.14|3.14||</ener:cadenaOriginal>
   <ener:idRefund>98</ener:idRefund>
  </ener:EstadoDeCuentaCombustible>
 </Addenda>
</Comprobante>
```

I need to get the text that is inside  (that long string)

Here's how I start the c# code

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("Route");

XmlNamespaceManager xnm = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);

xnm.AddNamespace("Documento", "http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/2");
xnm.AddNamespace("ener", "http://www.enercard.com.mx/cfd");
```

I've tried various ways...

```
//strOriginalString = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//Documento:Addenda", xnm).FirstChild.SelectSingleNode("//ener:cadenaOriginal", xnm).InnerText;
//strOriginalString = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//Documento:Addenda//ener:EstadoDeCuentaCombustible", xnm).FirstChild.SelectSingleNode("//ener:cadenaOriginal", xnm).InnerText;
//strOriginalString = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//Documento:Addenda/Documento:cadenaOriginal", xnm).InnerXml;
```

this 3 ways always throw an exception...

I found another way that doesn't throw an exception, but it doesn't get the string

```
XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("/Addenda/EstadoDeCuentaCombustible");
strOriginalString = "";

foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    XmlNode child = node.SelectSingleNode("./cadenaOriginal");

    if (child != null)
    {
        strOriginalString = child.InnerText;
        break;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? or is there another way that I can get the string inside

Comment: I'm confused. Your XML declares the `ener` namespace prefix as an empty namespace, but your mapping says something else. Also, the mapping has the `Documento` namespace, but there is no trace of that in your document.

Answer (score 1):

I find Linq2Xml easier to use. (Assuming you have a valid namespace in `xmlns:ener=""`).

```
var xDoc = XDocument.Load(filename);
XNamespace ener = "your name space for ex ,http://www.enercard.com.mx/cfd";
var result = xDoc.Descendants(ener + "cadenaOriginal").First().Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your second attempt looks the closest to what should work:

```
//strOriginalString = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("//Documento:Addenda//ener:EstadoDeCuentaCombustible", xnm).FirstChild.SelectSingleNode("//ener:cadenaOriginal", xnm).InnerText;
```

But switch to this(edited):

```
//strOriginalString = doc.SelectSingleNode("//ener:cadenaOriginal", xnm).InnerText;
```

Comment: throws the following exception
Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function.

Comment: I should have left your ", xnm" inside the SelectSingleNode call; editing answer

Comment: I should also note that I did have to edit the xml file to include the xmlns:ener declaration like others have also mentioned being needed.

Answer (score 1):

This is somewhat simplified, and you'll need to deal with the namespace problems (one I note below), but otherwise, this is the basic construct:

```
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        try { doc.Load("c:\\temp\\test.xml"); }
        catch (Exception ex) { }
        XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
        String strOriginalString = "";

        foreach (XmlNode node in root.SelectNodes("/Comprobante/Addenda"))
        {
            XmlNode child = node.SelectSingleNode("EstadoDeCuentaCombustible/cadenaOriginal");
            if (child != null)
            {
                strOriginalString = child.InnerText;
                break;
            }
        }
```

There's an issue with `<ener:EstadoDeCuentaCombustible xmlns:ener="">` as the empty namespace is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `xmlns:ener` declaration on your XML document:

```
<ener:EstadoDeCuentaCombustible xmlns:ener="http://www.enercard.com.mx/cfd">
```

Fix that and you'll be able to use something like this:

```
string xpath = "/Comprobante/Addenda/ener:EstadoDeCuentaCombustible";
foreach (XmlNode estado in doc.SelectNodes(xpath, xnm))
{
    Console.WriteLine("ener:cadenaOriginal={0}", 
        estado.SelectSingleNode("ener:cadenaOriginal", xnm).InnerText);
}
```